# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having problem while trying to upload my app archive to AppStore with Xcode. When I am trying to submit my app, I get error "No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier [my bundle id] is correct."

- My Bundle ID is 100% correct (I did cmd+c, cmd+v) from my iTunes Connect page.
- My App is created in iTunes Connect. Moreover, I have uploaded some versions to it and have tested them in TestFlight. Now something seems to be broken somehow.
- I am logged in with right account. I am able to upload other apps for this account, but this one doesn't want to work.
- I can't even delete this app from iTunes Connect (cause my app hasn't yet been submitted to AppStore) or change bundle id.
- Apple Support couldn't provide any helpful information.

Has anyone run into this problem? Are there any ways to solve it? Is it possible that it is an Apple-side bug?

I really need help. Will appreciate any kind of advice. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use the "Application Loader" utility? If not, you should try.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've saved my day!
Using Application Loader has solved my problem.

Comment: @ArikSegal Could you add that as an answer? It worked for me, too.

Comment: @jaime I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: For me even with Application Loader is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the "Application Loader" utility? If not, you should try.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - simple trick: Restarting my computer changed everything.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: Well, yes - it answers the first 2 of the 3 asked questions ("Has anyone run into this problem? Are there any ways to solve it? Is it possible that it is an Apple-side bug?"). That's at least one more than the accepted answer does.